# PHP RecursiveIteratorIterator making a website slow to respond?

Tags: php, iterator, php-5.5

PHP `RecursiveIteratorIterator` seems to be making my website very slow on each browser request.

Any other options can I use instead of `RecursiveIteratorIterator`?

Or maybe there is something not correct in my code below for using `RecursiveIteratorIterator`?

```
$mainDirectories = [
    'local/app/',
    'local/ioc/',
    'local/controller/',
    'local/model/',
    'local/helper/'
]

    foreach($mainDirectories as $pathDirectory)
    {
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator
        (
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($pathDirectory), 
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
        );

        foreach ($iterator as $fileObject) 
        {
            if ($fileObject->isDir()) 
            {
                // Replace any backslash to '/'.
                $pathnameReplace = str_replace('\\', '/', $fileObject->getPathname());
                //print_r($pathnameReplace);

                // Explode the folder path.
                $array = explode("/",$pathnameReplace);

                // Get the actual folder.
                $folder = end($array);
                //print_r($folder);

                // Stop proccessing if the folder is a dot or double dots.
                if($folder === '.' || $folder === '..') {continue;} 
                //var_dump($fileObject->getPathname());
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is meant to list the sub dirs in each main dirs. For instance,

There are sub dirs in 'local/model/',

```
article/
nav/
```

So result will be,

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'local/model/article/' (length=19)
  1 => string 'local/model/nav/' (length=15)
```

and so on.

Comment: Could you explain what  your code is supposed to do?

Comment: it lists the sub dirs in each main dirs.

Comment: It looks good to me, did you already check how many files/folders there are? Scanning a directory with thousands files (eg. cache files) could talk a "while" because disc operations are always very expensive operations (seeking the position of the disc). Jfyi use $fileObject->isDot() instead of checking for '.' or '..' ;)

Comment: you know about `FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` and `SplFileInfo::getBasename()` (maybe even `AppendIterator`) ? - just sayin'

Comment: @andreashager i have about 20 sub folders and it will scale up in the future.

Comment: @birdspider I don't know about that. but thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I now use `glob` instead `foreach(glob($mainDirectory.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) 
            {
                $subDirectories2[] = $dir;
            }` which does the same thing but seems a lot faster.